# Cakephp and jquery find form element by name

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp, find, element

Is there anything specific in Cakephp for jquery to know, when a form element needs to be found?

When I try to find a form element by its name:

```
data[Model][Model][id]
```

It cannot be found by:

```
jQuery('#ModelForm input[name=data[Model][Model][id]]')
```

Also tried:

```
jQuery("input[name='data[Model][Model][id]']" , "#ModelForm")
```

HTML markup:

```
<form action="..." class="form-horizontal" id="ModelForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Label</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input text"><input style="display: none;" name="data[Model][Model][id]" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="ids" data-role="tagsinput" type="text"></div>
      ...
```

Thanks for troubleshooting it. And sorry for confusion. I think I found the answer. While the script, I am using, can be called out right after the jquery lib, other related function needs to be called after the document/page is ready. That was the mistake I did.

Comment: Please show relevant generated html for same element

Comment: I have added the html markup

Comment: Since ID's are unique in a page, why can't you just use the id ? `$('#ids').doSomething()`

Comment: And what does `jQuery('#ModelForm input[name=data[Model][Model][id]]')` return?

Comment: Also selector seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/0Laswyke/ as long as quote the name

Comment: @charlietfl That was the first thing I did, and it didn't work. I am not sure now, but I use the bootstrap tag plugin https://github.com/timschlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput. and maybe it overwrites something I cannot figure out.

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: @u_mulder  `Object[input#ids.form-control property value = "" attribute value = "null"]`

Comment: Then why do you tell `It cannot be found by`?

Comment: I set a function from tagsinput plugin, with no effects so it is either not the correct way of marking up this element, or there is a bug/conflict.